# ASP MVC Навигация между представлениями в Главном Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Приветствую!

Пишу небольшое ASP приложение, параллельно осваивая эту технологию. На данный момент хочу осуществить навигацию между разными вью через главную страницу-шаблон. Итак, на шаблоне `_Layout` имеется разметка :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Главная</a></li>
        <li><a>О нас</a></li>
        <li><a>Регистрация</a></li>
        <li><a>Лучшие Специалисты</a></li>
        <li><a>Лучшие Работодатели</a></li>
        <li><a>Обратная Связь</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Страница Регистрации:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Registration</h2>
<span>Тут форма для регистрации</span>
```

и Главная Страница :

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Main</h2>
<span>Тут главная форма</span>
```

Оба представления имеют контроллеры приблизительно одинакового содержания:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Registration
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Вопрос - как возвращать разные представления, в зависимости от того что было выбрано в `<ul>` списке, так что бы разметка самого `_Layout` оставалась на месте и макет был идентичен на всех страницах ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `@Html.ActionLink`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Имя", "Action", "Controller")
```

Пример:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Главная", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("О нас", "About", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Еще `@Html.ActionLink` есть перегрузки, можно передавать параметры и задавать стили.